# Viewing the Account Name of multiple Apps in iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes, applications, user-account

We have several people using the same computer *and* the same user account. However, each person has a different iTunes account.

With respect to the Apps section, is there anyway to view the ownership of multiple Apps? I can only find out the Account Name (purchaser) of one App at a time, via <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

How can I get this information all at once?

iMac Intel 2.8GHz Core 2 Duo, Mac OS X (10.5.4), 2GB RAM

Answer (score 2):

Just click on the app

[image]

and push Command + "I", or right-click on the app and click "Get Info", or click on the app and navigate to File>Get Info (sixth command from the bottom).

[image]

All three of these will allow you to see the account name and email of the person who purchased them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Neil, I think unfortunately it is not possible to do this at current, there doesn't seem to be a sort for 'Account Name' perhaps you should suggest it on [apples user forums.](https://discussions.apple.com/index.jspa)

Edit: There is a similar post on the forum, however the solution looks a little bit involved: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2323398?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: The referenced Applescript only seems to work for media content, not for apps.